# Skip rows in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm doing a budgeting spreadsheet in excel. Along the top, the columns are headed for each budget item I need to account for. The rows are each labelled with dates on a daily basis. At the end of each week I have a row that balances the totals for each week.

My question is this, I want to be able to fill down the date column and any other columns that  have identical or pattern data, but I'd like to skip the total balance row that I have at the end of each week, thus maintaining the date sequence.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll caveat this by saying I'm not sure how your data is set up (nor where blank rows are, etc.), so if it is horribly wrong that is my excuse :) One way that you could do it (at least with the date - not sure what your other columns are like) is to populate the first row of the data with the column, the second with an actual date, and then drop this formula in the third row (assuming it is in column `A`):

```
=IFERROR(IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=7,"Total",A2+1),A1+1)
```

This assumes that you are starting the week on a Sunday (you can toy with the `WEEKDAY(A2)=` number to get it how you want). General idea is that it uses your first date as the starting point, increments the date if the previous date isn't the end of the week, but if it is then writes `Total`. Then for the next row, if taking the `WEEKDAY()` causes an error (as it will with string `Total`), it takes the row above that an increments by one. Not sure if this gets you want you want, but hope it points you in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

I don't use autofill for sequences, instead I use a formula that adds one to the cell containing the previous value.

Comment: will this solve my problem? If so, how?

Comment: I would put the date before the start date in A1, in A3 i would put =A1+1, in A4 put =A3+1, and then you can figure it out.

Comment: How is this any better than just manually entering the dates?? What if i'm budgeting the next three years? This solution wil take forever...

Comment: You can use the copy function for that. The trick is to set up your formulas so that they will do the right thing.